# PHP Function to return string

Tags: php, string, function

I am fairly new to PHP. I have a function which checks the cost of price. I want to return the variable from this function to be used globally:

```
<?
function getDeliveryPrice($qew){
    if ($qew=="1"){
        $deliveryPrice="60";
    } else {
        $deliveryPrice="20";
    }
    return $deliveryPrice;                          
}
// Assuming these two next lines are on external pages..
getDeliveryPrice(12);
echo $deliveryPrice; // It should return 20

?>
```

Comment: @M1th I wish there was some downvote on comments for fanboy mantra.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: There is: flagging comments for moderator attention. Already did so, will be gone in a little while.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Just flag it.

Comment: Thanks. I have flagged. Surely I asked in the correct manor so why the OMG so newb attitude.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Remember, this is the internet. For every polite, helpful and friendly person there are hundreds of the opposite. SO is pretty good at weeding out the folks we don't want but it is sort of whack-a-mole :)

Comment: Shame his comment is removed as in the fact that it can't be highlighted. Looks like I am speaking to a brick wall now. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid It was flagged, mods can still see everything as it was. If that chap keeps it up, he will be running on ever-thinning ice. Just ignore it after it is flagged. Not worth fussing over.

Comment: What have you tried to make it work? If the value is returned, why not store it in a value? And if you really want to use a global variable, why not use a global variable as documented?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should simply store the return value in a variable:

```
$deliveryPrice = getDeliveryPrice(12);
echo $deliveryPrice; // will print 20
```

The `$deliveryPrice` variable above is a *different* variable than the `$deliveryPrice` inside the function. The latter is not visible outside the function because of [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Also worth mentioning that in the comparison it is being checked against a string value perhaps?

Comment: @Fluffeh: Eh... no practical difference. I wouldn't mention that to a beginner.

Comment: Is there somehow I can say `returnAsGlobal $deliveryPrice;`

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: There is, but that's one of the worst practices available to you *and* it's only "global or nothing" -- there is no option to say "make this available to the caller" if the calling code is not in the global scope. Take my advice and do not go there. There is also the possibility of the function accepting an "out parameter" by reference but again: this is not how that feature should be used.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?
function getDeliveryPrice($qew){
    if ($qew=="1"){
        $deliveryPrice="60";
    } else {
        $deliveryPrice="20";
    }
    return $deliveryPrice;                          
}

$price = getDeliveryPrice(12);
echo $price;

?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
function getDeliveryPrice($qew){
   global $deliveryPrice;
    if ($qew=="1"){
        $deliveryPrice="60";
    } else {
        $deliveryPrice="20";
    }
    //return $deliveryPrice;                          
}
// Assuming these two next lines are on external pages..
getDeliveryPrice(12);
echo $deliveryPrice; // It should return 20

?>
```

Comment: sheri prajul :)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 2):

As some alrady said, try using classes for this.

```
class myClass
{
    private $delivery_price;

    public function setDeliveryPrice($qew = 0)
    {
        if ($qew == "1") {
            $this->delivery_price = "60";
        } else {
            $this->delivery_price = "20";
        }
    }

    public function getDeliveryPrice()
    {
        return $this->delivery_price;
    }
}
```

Now, to use it, just initialize the class and do what you need:

```
$myClass = new myClass();
$myClass->setDeliveryPrice(1);

echo $myClass->getDeliveryPrice();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what's the point in using a class here? Which problem does it solve? The variable itself isn't made global through this