# use function inside PHP SQL

Tags: php

hey guys I have an SQL in PHP with PDO method and I want use my function inside this SQL.

My function:

```
function columns(){
    return "id,name";
}
```

My SQL code:

```
try{
    $connection->beginTransaction();
    $connection->exec("INSERT INTO table (".columns().") VALUES (1,'John')");
    $connection->commit();
}catch(...){
...
}
```

But its not working what can i do help me please.

The SQL is becoming like this :

```
INSERT INTO table() VALUES (1,'John')
```

The problem is the `columns()` function is not returning on the SQL but if we print the `columns()` function its will print. (tested with `print_r(columns());`)

Comment: Be more specific. What isn't working? What is the error?

Comment: @Jacobm001 the function is not working on SQL. question is edited also.

Comment: I don't see why the function's return value is dropped. Does it work in a variable? Is it possible that your function is overwritten in your scope (class and such)?

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' yes its possible but I don't think its gonna work on class also

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour in the question.

Comment: Do you actually have a table called, `table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to store the answer of that function and add it to your string

```
try{
    $mycolumnname = columns();
    $connection->beginTransaction();
    $sql="INSERT INTO table (".$mycolumnname.") VALUES (1,'John')";
    $connection->exec($sql);
    $connection->commit();
}catch(...){
...
}
```

Comment: Good for debugging, but I don't think it should make any difference.

Comment: Glad to hear that, can you elaborate? What is the difference joining the query string using intermediate variable instead of the functions return value?

Comment: @nbk I tried this before you but it's not gonna work i even used this way : `INSERT INTO table ($mycolumnname)` both are same and not gonna work. still same error like before.

Comment: look there are countle4ss threads here like yours see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296624/php-function-to-return-string

Comment: @nbk no its difference. its 100% something else

Comment: so where it is different.

Comment: @nbk I don't have problem with returning or printing value I having problem with using the returned value on SQL

Comment: not with me, it works straight forward  are you sure that the query actually works?